# "img" in "td" and "background-image" of "td" have different heights

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I have two images:

- `left.jpg` is `250px`-by-`47px`,
- `right.jpg` is `1px`-by-`47px`.

These are put into the two cells of the same table row:

- `left.jpg` goes into the left cell in an `<img>` tag,
- `right.jpg` goes into the right cell, as its `background-image`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="left.jpg" /></td>
      <td background="right.jpg" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

I made a [jsfiddle test page](http://jsfiddle.net/AQtNk/). There is a problem with the rendered result: the cells are `52px` high instead of `47px`, which creates a white strip below the image in the left cell.

[image]

**Question:** How can I make the cell height `47px`, and eliminate the white strip? Thanks!

**Update:** None of these help:

```
tbody { height: 47px; }
tr { height: 47px; }
td { height: 47px; }
```

Comment: Why would you use a table for this?!

Comment: what are you trying to do ? There is probably simpler way

Comment: Set the width of the `<td>` in CSS and give it a `background-image`. Also, the way you’re doing a table is totally wrong and the way you’re doing a gradient is totally wrong. Even if you have to support IE5, you can still tile and repeat vertically a `background-image` over a `background-color`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster This is legacy code. The real code is much more complex, I extracted the smallest part which shows the problem.

Comment: @minitech I know this code is $#!+. I just have to solve the problem in a non-invasive way if possible.

Comment: Setting a height to `td` does not work because heights in table cells are interpreted as minimum values.  Table cells will expand vertically as needed to enclose their content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image is shown as an inline element and it has some white space below the baseline.

Try:

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/RL5AE/

Answer (score 3):

Images add a vertical bottom padding in case text is to be entered. To get rid of that, Add either of the below CSS properties to your image:

1. `display: block;`
2. `vertical-align: top;`
3. `float: left;`

I recommend `display: block;`